# SVG not rendering in google chrome

Tags: css, svg

I would like to know why my svg is not showing in chrome browser but works on safari

```html
<svg width="325" height="214" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 325 214" fill="none">
     <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
     <path d="M4 7L321 0V199L4 206V7Z" fill="#441D76"/>
     </g>
     <defs>
     <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="325" height="214" 
     filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
     <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
     <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
     <feOffset dy="4"/>
     <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
     <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0.25 0"/>
     <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" 
     result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
     <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" 
     result="shape"/>
     </filter>
     </defs>
    </svg>
```

The image is not showing in google chrome

Comment: don't forget to add relevant tag if you want to get answers. Not adding the SVG tag will give you low chance for a good answer and adding the JS tag is useless

Comment: Renders the same in Chrome and Firefox for me.

Comment: In your feColorMatrix, try changing the number 127 to 0.5.